# Custom \def command that appends to the newly defined command

Tags: macros

I have several macros with a similar structure, for example:

```
\def\firstmacro#1{\myinitializer ...actual code... \myfinalizer}
\def\secondmacro#1{\myinitializer ...actual code... \myfinalizer}
\def\thirdmacro#1{\myinitializer ...actual code... \myfinalizer}
```

(`\myinitializer` and `\myfinalizer` are only placeholders for more complicated initializer code.) I was thinking how I could simplify this common structure by defining a custom `\def` macro. I arrived at

```
\def\custom@def#1{
  \def#1{\myinitializer\csname custom@#1\endcsname}
  \expandafter\def\csname custom@#1\endcsname
}

\custom@def\firstmacro#1{...actual code... \myfinalizer}
\custom@def\secondmacro#1{...actual code... \myfinalizer}
\custom@def\thirdmacro#1{...actual code... \myfinalizer}
```

So `\custom@def` defines the wanted command to call `\myinitializer` and pass to an internal command that contains the actual definition. Everything after the first argument of `\def` is passed to the `\def` of that internal macro. However, with this approach, `\myfinalizer` still needs to be specified explicitly. Any idea how I could eliminiate this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `etoolbox` provides a `\appto` and `\preto` which could be used to append or prefix some code to an existing macro. However, in your case I would directly collect the parameter text and replacement text as macro arguments and add the init and final code around it.

You can collect everything until the next opening `{` by placing a `#` before the `{` in the macro definition. This way you collect the macro name and the parameter text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\custom@def#1#{%
    \@custom@def{#1}%
}
\def\@custom@def#1#2{%
  \def#1{\myinitializer#2\myfinalizer}%
}


\custom@def\mytest{test}
\show\mytest

\custom@def\mytest#1#2{(#1)(#2)}

\show\mytest

\makeatother
\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Gives:

```
> \mytest=macro:
->\myinitializer test\myfinalizer .
l.14 \show\mytest

? 
> \mytest=macro:
#1#2->\myinitializer (#1)(#2)\myfinalizer .
l.18 \show\mytest
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. For those interested: See exercise 20.6 in the TeXbook and the note about "a special extension" two paragraphs above.